# Best approach to first use of Python with Google Sheets, to query API in GitHub and Jira?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, github-api, jira-rest-api

This question is about process / approach, more so than how to write the code itself.  I'm a process learner, so this is the part that's creating personal anxiety for me.

I am very much a beginner, and still learning about importing libraries and the like.  I have an idea for what I'd like to be able to do, for a Capstone Project, as I learn, however.

I have a spreadsheet that I use each Sprint as par of our Capacity Planning process.  I want to use Python to query target tickets in our client's GitHub (while logged in) account, and our Jira account, to pull specific data into the cells that I currently populate manually.  Others have expressed interest in seeing what I come up with, as they use the same Google sheets template similarly.

From [Sheets for Developers > API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), through trial and error, I should be able to figure out how to generally import data into Google Sheets.  Likewise, this [GoTrained Python Tutorial](https://python.gotrained.com/search-github-api/) looks like it has an approach for obtaining information from GitHub API.  I'm fairly certain that I can find similar for Jira (though the first site that I tried wanted to use a fake "captcha" script to trick me into accepting notifications from the site, which was a red flag, to me).

But which are the quality, most efficient approaches?  Especially for a starting out Python beginner, like myself?  The last time I coded was 15-20 years ago, using LPC to build rooms/mobs/objects on a MU*, accessed via Telnet protocol.

I need to learn more about how to set up the program, and which libraries might be useful; and the best way - after decomposition - to identify the components and which methods to use, generally, in solving for the project goal:

- import select field data from Jira and GitHub to a Sheet, using Python

  - how do I know which libraries are best to import, like Tkinter, for functions that I will need (this one came up in search for creating dropdown lists in Python, so that the Repo names can be standardized).
- seeing lots of references to REST-api, but we haven't talked about that in course yet

  - what are some quality resources to learn more about principles that I should understand better before attempting this project?

    - w3schools.com is on my radar, but it is also extensive -- not sure if there are resources honed in on this type of "challenge"